# Cover a period with multiple (smaller) periods

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a period of time (travel), e.g. `2015-04-01` - `2015-04-23`.

Now, there a several other periods (conditions), e.g.:
`2015-03-27` - `2015-04-02`
`2015-04-04` - `2015-04-18`
`2015-04-02` - `2015-04-06`
`2015-04-14` - `2015-04-16`
`2015-04-23` - `2015-04-30`

Here a sketch (black is the travel and red are the condition periods)
[image]

The goal is to cover the whole travel with conditions without gaps (if possible), overlappings and duplicates.

So my final conditions would look like this:
`2015-04-01` - `2015-04-02`
`2015-04-02` - `2015-04-03`
`2015-04-03` - `2015-04-18`
`2015-04-23` - `2015-04-23`

And the new sketch:
[image]

The conditions don't have a specific order when I get them.

My current implementation is pretty huge and buggy. Is there a proven way to do this?

Please note the period dates  are examples and the sketches aren't accurate.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but... Do you have a practical use case?  Would you share the code you have now?

Comment: The travel could stand for a stay in a hotel. When a condition covers a few days of the stay, the hotel price for these days is reduced. I want to achieve the lowest price for the whole stay. I'll try to post some code.

Comment: do you need only the conditions that begin and within the travel time ?

Comment: condition can or must-not overlap each other ?

Comment: I'm interested in the days of the conditions which are in my travel time. The conditions must not overlap, because it's not valid to have more than one discount for a day.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a "***quck***" demo ... 
I hope is clear enough to understand.

> Your dates:

```
$travel = array('from'=>'20150401', 'to'=>'20150423');
$conditions = array(
    'condition_1' => array('from'=>'20150327', 'to'=>'20150402'),
    'condition_2' => array('from'=>'20150404', 'to'=>'20150418'),
    'condition_3' => array('from'=>'20150402', 'to'=>'20150406'),
    'condition_4' => array('from'=>'20150414', 'to'=>'20150416'),
    'condition_5' => array('from'=>'20150423', 'to'=>'20150430')
);
```

> Functions to prepare dates:

```
// CONVERTS DATES INTO TIME
function get_times($from, $to){
    preg_match('/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', preg_replace("/\D/m", '', $from), $d); $from = @mktime(0, 0, 0, $d[2], $d[3], $d[1]);
    preg_match('/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/', preg_replace("/\D/m", '', $to), $d); $to = @mktime(0, 0, 0, $d[2], $d[3], $d[1]);
    $delta = $to-$from;
    return array('from'=>$from, 'to'=>$to, 'delta'=>$delta, 'days'=>$delta/86400);
}

// PARSE MORE DATA INTO $travel & $conditions
function parse_dates($travel, $conditions){
    $travel['times'] = get_times($travel['from'], $travel['to']);
    $applicable_conditions = array();
    foreach($conditions as $i=>$cond){
        if($cond['from']<=$travel['to'] && $cond['to']>=$travel['from']){
            $cond['times'] = get_times($cond['from']<$travel['from']?$travel['from']:$cond['from'], $cond['to']>$travel['to']?$travel['to']:$cond['to']);
            $applicable_conditions[$i] = $cond;
        }
    }
    return array('travel'=>$travel, 'conditions'=>$applicable_conditions);
}
```

> Just an example, you may wanna change this into something more suitable for you:

```
// (mockup) DISPLAY GRAPHICS
function show_graph($dates){
    $w = 600; $w2 = 100; $h = 30; $bg = '#4682B4'; $col = '#FFFFFF';
    $day = '<div style="display:inline-block; width:'.(round($w/$dates['travel']['times']['days'])-2).'px; border:1px solid '.$col.'; height:'.($h-2).'px;';
    $day_blue = $day.' background-color:'.$bg.';">';
    $day_red = $day.' background-color:red;">';
    $day_empty = $day.' background-color:white;">';
    $day_black = $day.' background-color:black;">';
    $cd = '</div>';
    $days = ''; $cond_days = $day_nocond = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$dates['travel']['times']['days']; $i++){
        $daytime = $dates['travel']['times']['from']+(86400*$i);
        $days .= $day_blue.$i.$cd;
        $day_havecond[$i] = false;
        foreach($dates['conditions'] as $name=>$cond){
            $is_cond = $daytime>=$cond['times']['from'] && $daytime<=$cond['times']['to'];
            $day_box = $is_cond ? ( $day_havecond[$i] ? $day_black.$i.$cd : $day_red.$i.$cd ) : $day_empty.'&nbsp;'.$cd;
            if($is_cond && !$day_havecond[$i]){ $day_havecond[$i] = true;}
            @$cond_days[$name] .= $day_box;
        }
    }
    $o = '
        <div style="display:inline-block; width:'.$w2.'px;">Travel</div>
        <div style="display:inline-block; color:'.$col.';">'.$days.'</div><br/>';
    foreach($cond_days as $name=>$days){
        $o .= '
        <div style="display:inline-block; width:'.$w2.'px;">'.$name.'</div>
        <div style="display:inline-block; color:'.$col.';">'.$days.'</div><br/>';
    }
    return '<div style="width:'.($w+$w2).'px;">'.$o.'</div>' ;
}
```

> this is how you produce the graphics:

```
# USAGE
$dates = parse_dates($travel, $conditions);
echo show_graph($dates);

# DEBUG
echo '<hr>'; print_r($dates);
```